# Поиск максимумов в скользящем окне Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Недавно начал изучать Python3.

Суть проблемы. Есть таблица из нескольких столбцов и несколько десятков тысяч строк. Пусть столбец называется "А".

Нужно найти максимум в столбце "А" за 100 предыдущих строк и записать этот максимум в новый столбец "B". Записи в столбце "B" начинаются со 101 строчки. На 102 строчке столбца "B" должен быть максимум из диапазона 2-101 столбца "А". И так до самого конца таблицы.

Также нужно определять позицию найденного в столбце А максимума, например 24 место в диапазоне 1-100. (Если несколько одинаковых значений, то брать самое верхнее). И находить сумму в диапазоне 24-100 по столбцу "X". Эту сумму записывать в новый столбец "C". Записи в столбце "C" начинать также со 101 строки. Если для следующей строки в диапазоне 2-101 максимум в столбце остался на 24 месте, то сумма по столбцу "Х" рассчитывается по строкам 24-101 и записывается в ячейку С-102. И так до самого конца таблицы, как со столбцом "B".

В Excel такие вещи делаются элементарно, а в Python не могу найти как это сделать.

Comment: постарайтесь ограничиваться одним вопросом. Так это может пригодиться будущим посетителям SO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы найти максимум в скользящем окне в Pandas существует метод [Series.rolling()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html).

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [134]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(100, size=30)})

In [135]: df
Out[135]:
     A
0   49
1   93
2   62
3   40
4   59
5   52
6   97
..  ..
23  30
24  36
25  46
26  38
27  76
28  39
29  63

[30 rows x 1 columns]
```

пример использования метода `.rolling(window=3)`:

```
In [136]: df['B'] = df['A'].rolling(3).max()

In [137]: df
Out[137]:
     A     B
0   49   NaN
1   93   NaN
2   62  93.0
3   40  93.0
4   59  62.0
5   52  59.0
6   97  97.0
..  ..   ...
23  30  66.0
24  36  53.0
25  46  46.0
26  38  46.0
27  76  76.0
28  39  76.0
29  63  76.0

[30 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это то, что требуется для первой части вопроса. Помогите еще со второй частью. Как можно найти сумму в скользящем окне Pandas от найденного максимума до конца окна?

Comment: @Maksim_19, задайте отдельный вопрос. SO - ресурс, на который приходят с поисковиков по конкретному запросу. Соответственно, здесь принято задавать конкретные вопросы, с которыми возникли трудности в реализации, а не писать тех. задания для готовых решений.

Comment: @Maksim_19, примите ответ, если помогло, а то ваш вопрос висячий :)